# Why am I getting an Application Error error page for my brand new app hosted by Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am pretty much brand new to RoR and such.

I am following a video tutorial to build my own web-based app, and I got to the step: 
git push heroku master

When in git bash, it was coming up with an error that claimed it couldn't compile ruby. Now, it says it is launched and deployed, but there is still the same error on the page for my app, http://infinite-mountain-6131.herokuapp.com/

Any ideas?? I can add files if needed.

Requested file(s):

app/config/application.rb from my comment

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# config/application.rb
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Myrubyblog
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Line 6 that was mentioned in my error is the config.assets.initialize which I put in there with line 5 as suggested to fix my problem.

This is what happens when I run the migrate as suggested (heroku run rake db:migrate)

```
Running 'rake db:migrate' attached to terminal... up, run.6274
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object
/app/config/application.rb:6:in '<top <required>>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in 'require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in '<top <required>'
<See full trace by running task with --trace>
```

Comment: Could you copy over any errors you see in your heroku logs? And possibly include a link to the tutorial?

Comment: There's a lot of old stuff out there that's no longer the right way to get a Rails app to run. I highly recommend you follow the "getting started" steps at Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4 . That's for v4. Google for the Rails 3 version if you're using that.

Comment: have you run the migrations do `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: try reading the logs with command `heroku logs`.

Comment: The tutorial I am following is an app by udemy called Learn RoR, and yes I did migrate. I do not remember which version I downloaded.

Comment: I tried to migrate again, and this came up:

Running 'rake db:migrate' attached to terminal... up, run.6274
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object
/app/config/application.rb:6:in '<top <required>>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in 'require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in '<top <required>'
<See full trace by running task with --trace>

Comment: Can you show the tutorial video ? One problem u should notice that Heroko does not allow sqlite gem, so remove it before deploy to Heroku

Comment: I removed it according to the video by replacing the lines with sqlite in them with the postgresql. This is the link to the video: https://www.udemy.com/learn-ruby-on-rails-from-scratch/#/lecture/267737

Comment: If you get error in `config/application.rb` line 6 it means you should look there. Can you show this file?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, there are two types of error you can get when hosting a Rails app on Heroku:

**Heroku Error**

[image]

-

**Rails Error**

[image]

--

**Error**

The difference between the two is important - `rails` errors will only occur if your operating environment is actually "running" your Rails application. `Heroku` errors will occur if your operating environment / Heroku will not load correctly

The problem you have is definitely a *Heroku* issue - one which is typically created by a lack of `db` connectivity. The way to fix this issue is to ensure your application has all the necessities to run - most notably the correct `db`

You'll be best using the following:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

However, I appreciate this won't be the only issue you'll have

---

**Heroku Deployment**

As you've said you're a "beginner" to ROR, let me give you some ideas

Firstly, when you write a question on here, it helps to divulge as much information as possible - typically from the logs, or any other specific error handling mechanism

Secondly, you want to ensure that everything required to get your application running has been achieved. Most notably, when you mention Heroku `cannot compile the Ruby application`, you'll need to provide information on *why* this is the case -- there'll probably be a `gem` conflict (SQLite3) or similar

Thirdly, you need to ensure you have migrated your database. This is the single biggest reason why "Heroku errors" appear - deploying your Rails app doesn't mean the migrations you made locally will persist - you need to ensure you have the `db` updated as you require, which can be done as follows:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I ran the migrate multiple times, and I was unable to find the reason why in the log

Comment: One thing which helps us is if you install the [`logentries` addon](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries)

Comment: I am unable to due to the limitations on my computer

Comment: lol - it's a Heroku addon - why can't you install that on your system?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't have the time before but it is done now.